# What is the effect of ignoring DTD specification in java?

Tags: java, code-injection, dtd, xml

Code analyzer tool is notifying about `XML Entity Expansion Injection` because there is no DTD specification implemented.

So i want to disable to the DTD specification check by

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```

So I would like to know

1. Will it break actual code flow?
2. Will it cause anymore issues?
3. Is there any other way to handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use  parsers safely, you have to explicitly disable XXE in the parser you use. The following describes how to disable XXE in the most commonly used XML parsers for Java.

**JAXP DocumentBuilderFactory and SAXParserFactory**

Both DocumentBuilderFactory and SAXParserFactory XML Parsers can be configured using the same techniques to protect them against XXE.
Only the DocumentBuilderFactory example is presented here.

- The JAXP DocumentBuilderFactory setFeature method allows a developer
  to control which implementation-specific XML processor features are
  enabled or disabled

.

- Each XML processor implementation has its own features that govern how DTDs and external entities are processed.

For a syntax highlighted code snippet for DocumentBuilderFactory, click [here](https://gist.github.com/Prandium/dee14ea650ff7900f2c0).

For a syntax highlighted code snippet for SAXParserFactory, click [here](https://gist.github.com/asudhakar02/45e2e6fd8bcdfb4bc3b2).

**The links will give you full details how to use DTD for both the parsers.**

Xerces 1 Features:

Do not include external entities by setting this feature to false.
Do not include parameter entities by setting this feature to false.

Xerces 2 Features:

Disallow an inline DTD by setting this feature to true.
Do not include external entities by setting this feature to false.
Do not include parameter entities by setting this feature to false.
StAX and XMLInputFactory
StAX parsers such as XMLInputFactory allow various properties and features to be set.

To protect a Java XMLInputFactory from XXE, do this:

**xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false); // This disables DTDs entirely for that factory**

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, we should not disable DTD specification check.
Instead, use the EntityResolver to bypass DTD check in case a particular DTD is not found.

Here is how you create a DocumentBuilder that will ignore ALL external referenced entities, including DTDs:

```
final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
builder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
    @Override
        public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) {
                // it might be a good idea to insert a trace logging here that you are ignoring publicId/systemId
                return new InputSource(new StringReader("")); // Returns a valid dummy source
        }
    });
```

Alternatively, you could also do the following:

```
final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
builder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
          public InputSource resolveEntity(java.lang.String publicId, java.lang.String systemId)
                 throws SAXException, java.io.IOException
          {
            if (publicId.equals("--DTDpublicID--"))
              // this deactivates the DTD
              return new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>".getBytes()));
            else return null;
          }
});
```

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it helped you ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

without disabling DTD for xml, you can try using "SECURE_PROCESSING"
This takes care of xml parsing vulnerable to XXE and dos attacks:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);

DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(input);
```